# ASP.NET Server Controls

Tags: asp.net

Web Server Controls and Html Server Controls both derive from System.Web.UI.Control.

What is the emphasis of the concept "server" here? Why "server" control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET is a server technology. These controls run on the web server, not on the client, in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

[see](http://www.extremeexperts.com/Net/FAQ/DiffBetweenServerandHTMLControls.aspx) this link. You will come to know about Web Server Controls and Html Server Controls.

Answer (score 1):

They are "Server" controls because they are a server-side abstraction.  They are used as controls on the server in your ASPX pages and may be directly manipulated in server-side code.  However, in request processing they are translated and emitted into the response as standard HTML and (possibly) JavaScript.  Thus, they are an abstraction that really only exists server side.

Comment: BTW, "HTML" server controls are just convenient wrappers for standard HTML tags that allow manipulation in code-behind, while the ASP.NET server controls typically provide some "enhanced" capability.  For example, while you can create a list of checkboxes in HTML and work with them, the CheckBoxList control provides a higher-level abstraction that is easier to work with in code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

For more information on server vs client control see the link below

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t64204-html-client-control-versus-html-server-control-versus-web-server-control.html